# Can we apply from and to to a animateMotion in svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a path through which I am animating a circle using `animateMotion`.

I want to determine the position of the circle according to time on the path. And also when I refresh the browser, instead of starting the animation from start, it should start from the current time.

How can I do this in SVG ? I tried using `from` but I guess it does not apply to `animateMotion`.

Any solutions, please?

Comment: When you refresh the browser it's a new page, it has no knowledge of the past unless you store something in a cookie or local storage that it can retrieve, As to the rest without a [mcve] and a clearer description of what you want your example to do that it currently doesn't do I suspect you won't get any answers here.

Comment: Please refer the following link. This is what i have done so far :     https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJaQyb

Comment: I want to move that circle based on time. Its duration will be 24 hours and depending on the cuurent time i want to place the circle on the path

Comment: You'd need trigger that with javascript, SMIL can't do things based on the current time unless you start it off with a script.